# Process for eating up CPU usage

Tags: c#, process, cpu-usage

This may be an "out-there" question, but here goes:

I'm currently writing a bandaid script for an application to check multiple processes under the same name, such as chrome.exe using a PerformanceCounter in C#.  Multiple instances of this process could possibly be running at the same time on the machine, so checking each one to see if it's above X% is needed.  Unfortunately, this application does not have a test environment and no easy way to set one up.

So my question is, does anyone know of a tool or "mock" process that I can use to drive up the CPU usage so that I can test my script on?  I'm basically wanting to create CPU usage.  Are there such testing tools out there?  Or is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: [Prime95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime95)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((a) =>
    {
        while (true) { }
    }));
}

while (true) { }
```

That will quite likely cause your CPU to jump up a fair bit given a thread will be going round and round non-stop without any break.

That gets up to about 85% utilisation on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for this, really like the programmatic approach to this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that online, using chrome. ==> http://www.fossiltoys.com/cpuload.html

Most realistic test ever!

Comment: I just tried that and their 100% utilisation test only used 30% on my machine, so it's probably not quite as accurate and the OP would like.

Comment: If you have a multicore CPU, you need to open multiple tabs/windows. (And all of them should be visible)